# Where does the Splunk add-in go?

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I downloaded this and have no idea where it goes:
https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/1908/
Google is not helping either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the details tab of the App description page of the page you linked:

To gather all data from a SharePoint server:

Download the "Splunk Add-on for Microsoft Windows" (v4.7.3 or later)
    and configure it to gather the Windows Event Logs for Security,
    Application and  System. Deploy this to all SharePoint servers.

Download the "Splunk Addon for Microsoft PowerShell" and deploy it
    to all  SharePoint servers.

Download this "Add-on for Microsoft
    SharePoint" and deploy it  "as downloaded" to the indexers and
    search heads.

Create indexes as appropriate for sharepoint, iis, and
    perfmon data (and  restart the indexers)

Create a copy of the
    TA-Sharepoint add-on and enable inputs, configure indexes as above,
    and deploy this to the audit reader. The spXXaudit and spXXinventory
    must be enabled for the appropriate version of SharePoint (XX=10 for
    SharePoint 2010 and 13 for SharePoint 2013).

For all other servers,
    enable all inputs EXCEPT spXXaudit and spXXinventory  (at the top of
    the inputs.conf file), configure indexes as above, and  then deploy
    the TA-SharePoint to all OTHER SharePoint servers  (except the audit
    reader).

Comment: Yeah, I just went through the details after asking this and found it, thank you.